# Real Macros on Javascript (Node JS)

Tags: javascript, node.js, macros

I want to know if I can implement real macros. I mean something that works in a pre-excecution stage.

Why? Take a look:

If I want to do some think like this:

```
1. function isset(obj){
2.    return typeof obj != 'undefined';
3. }
4. 
5. isset(monticuloDeBosta);
```

The "line 5" is going to trigger an error cause' monticuloDeBosta is not define.

If I could do:

```
#define isset(x) (typeof x != 'undefined')
```

It should work given the fact that 'isset(monticuloDeBosta)' is going to be replaced by '(typeof monticuloDeBosta != 'undefined')'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Javascript doesnt support macros. Use [clojurescript](http://clojure.org/clojurescript) or [Parenscript](https://common-lisp.net/project/parenscript/) or [SweetJS](http://sweetjs.org/). SweetJS from mozilla is my favourite, its easy to learn and pretty intuitive. To be honest, I havent tried Parenscript and used clojurescript once. Go to sweet's doc [here](http://sweetjs.org/doc/main/sweet.html#rule-macros)

Comment: It doesn't solve the problem I described above, but thanks you. I supposed it have solution.